# Set EMF EStructuralFeature with String Literal

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

Is it possible to set the value of an EStructuralFeature in EMF with a String literal?

Example:

```
someObject.set(intFeature, "1") 
someObject.set(stringFeature, "1")
```

After this I`d expect the value of the intFeature to be an integer with the value 1, and the value of the stringFeature to contain "1".

I suspect such a functionality is available because the EStructuralFeature::defaultValueLiteral is a String so it has to be parsed somehow, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this kind of things, you have to deal with the metamodel and the `EFactory`. By looking to the `setDefaultValue` from the `EStructuralFeature`, you can see that the `EFactory` of the `EStructuralFeature` type is used to build the value (only if the `EStructuralFeature` type is an `EDatatype`).

Here is a general snippet (we suppose we have an `EObject eobj`):

```
// We get the estructuralfeature
EStructuralFeature feature = eobj.eClass().getEStructuralFeature("myfeature");
// Is the feature type "primitive"
if (feature.getEType() instanceof EDataType) {
    EDataType dtype = (EDataType)ea.getEType();
    // We get the EFactory
    EFactory factory = feature.getEType().getEPackage().getEFactoryInstance();
    eobj.eSet(feature, factory.createFromString(dtype, "mystringvalue"));
}
```

And here is an example with UML:

```
Property p = UMLFactory.eINSTANCE.createProperty();
EStructuralFeature ea = p.eClass().getEStructuralFeature("lower");
... // if and stuffs
EFactory factory = ea.getEType().getEPackage().getEFactoryInstance();
p.eSet(ea, factory.createFromString((EDataType)ea.getEType(), "1"));
```